# angular material how to show spinner during an synchronous intensive task

Tags: angular

I want to show a spinner during the execution of an synchronous task. I set `showSpinner = true` before the task starts and `showSpinner=false` after it finishes. However, the spinner doesn't even show. I think this is because the expensive task block the DOM update for `*nfIf="showSpinner` which shows the spinner. How do I fix this? I am thinking of using lifecycle hooks but not sure how to.

```
updateImageData() {
    if (this.cropSizeChanged) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        var imgData = this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL(); //**expensive**
        this.editedImage = imgData;
        this.cropSizeChanged = false;
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }
    console.log("updated imageData");
    if(this.isTaggableImage) {
        setTimeout(() => {this.croppedImageBoundingRect = this.croppedImageRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();}, 100);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your spinner is not showing is that you are setting it to false straight away after making an expensive call. Now you can try two following things

1. If you expensive call returns the callback or promise which it should then set it to false in the call back. Normally in nagular we use observable so therefore the place to set the `this.showSpinner = false` will be inside subscribe.
2. Try code below

   `public updateImageData(){
             this.showSpinner = true;
             urthing.expensiveCall()
             setTimeout()=>{
                this.showSpinner = false;
             },3000);
           }`

Comment: this did not make any difference and I don't understand why it would. The function is synchronous as mentioned so there is no callback.

Comment: did you try the second approach? However I dont know, how can you make synchronous call in angular2 it is not possible and consider bad idea anyways

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the expensive call in a Promise like a so:

```
expensiveTask(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let imgData = this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
    resolve(imgData);
  }) 
}
```

And **then** put the rest of the logic once the promise has been resolved:

```
updateImageData() {
  if (this.cropSizeChanged) {
      this.showSpinner = true;
      this.expensiveTask().then(imgData => {
          this.editedImage = imgData;
          this.cropSizeChanged = false;
          this.showSpinner = false;
      });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: this will not make the task asynchronous. This would be equivalent to running the code that I have inside the updateImageData() function. The only way to prevent DOM update block is to run `this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();` in background thread and web worker won't work because this seems like a DOM related task.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Have you considered using zones? Perhaps running this utility outside Angular could help with performance but I'm no expert with zones tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executed on a single thread in the browser, so when you set showSpinne = true and run synchronious operation, browser can not render anything until code returns.
For heavy background use web worker https://angular.io/guide/web-worker this will free browser UI thread to be able to display the spinning icon and will calculate the changes on s separate worker thread.